# JavaFX 2.2: How do I change the title of an existing Tab?

Tags: java, tabs, javafx, javafx-2, title

According to the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html), there seems to be no way to change the title of a `Tab` in JavaFX. Is it true that we can only set the title upon construction of the Tab and thereafter we can never change it? Surely some reflection magic should be able to change the title?

Comment: Downvoter care to elaborate his decision a bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `tab.setText("...");`
See the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#setText%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: lol so the text IS the title??? hahaha I had a feeling it might be so. Will try it out soon and mark your answer as the accepted one if it is true. Thank you!